# How to solve real life difference equations using python

Tags: python, python-3.5, difference-equations

I want to solve a difference equation using python.

`y = x(n - 1) - (0.5(x(n-2) + x(n))`

`x` here is a long array of values. I want to plot `y` with respect to another time sequence array `t` using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/). I can plot `x` with `t`, but I am not able to generate the filtered signal `y`. I have tried the code below, but it seems I'm missing something. I am not getting the desired output.

```
from scipy import signal
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot
x = array(...)
t = array(...) # x and t are big arrays 
b = [-0.5, 1, -0.5]
a = 0
y = signal.lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1, zi=None) 
iplot([{"x": t, "y": y}])
```

However, the output is something like this.

```
>>>y
>>> array([-inf, ...,  nan])
```

Therefore, I am getting a blank graph.

UPDATE with examples of x and t (9 values each):

```
x = [3.1137561664814495,
 -1.4589810840917137,
 -0.12631870857936914,
 -1.2695030212226599,
 2.7600637824592158,
 -1.7810937909691049,
 0.050527483431747656,
 0.27158522344564368,
 0.48001109260160274]

t = [0.0035589523041146265,
 0.011991765409288035,
 0.020505576424579175,
 0.028935389041247817,
 0.037447199517441021,
 0.045880011487565042,
 0.054462819797731044,
 0.062835632533346342,
 0.071347441874490158]
```

Comment: Could you please add to your post shortened example data for `x` and `t`?

Comment: @Felix_Sim added some values from `x` and `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your problem is defining `a = 0`. When running your example, you get the following warning from [`SciPy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/):

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:1353: RuntimeWarning:

divide by zero encountered in true_divide

[-inf  inf  nan  nan  nan  inf -inf  nan  nan]
```

This division by zero is defined by value `a`. If you look at the documentation of [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter), it points out the following:

> a : array_like
>   The denominator coefficient vector in a 1-D sequence. If a[0] is not 1, then both a and b are normalized by a[0].

If you change `a = 0` to `a = 1` you should get output you desire, **although do consider that you might want to apply data normalization by a different factor.**

Comment: Silly mistake. The value 'a' goes to the denominator of the transfer function. It can not be zero. Thanks a lot. By the way, while running it on jupyter notebook I couldn't find any error. How could you get this error?

Comment: @tGeek I was running the script on the command line. You might have warnings disabled in your jupyter session. I'm sure a quick Google search will help.